# NSOperationQueue is not being cancelled

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsoperationqueue, nsthread

I am using `PageViewController` where I may have more than one image as a content. I am getting image as follows from the Service. However, when user clicks to dismiss the viewcontroller while network operation still going on, app crashes.

```
queue = [[NSOperationQueue alloc] init];
operation = [NSBlockOperation blockOperationWithBlock:^{
            [self addAllImages];
                dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
                     [self pageViewcontrollerSetup];
            });
        }];
     [queue addOperation:operation];
}

- (void) addAllImages
{
    self.pageImages =[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:self.pageControl.numberOfPages];

    for(id key in [[[pElements objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pdetail"] objectForKey:@"images"]) {
        NSString *productURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", PRODUCT_URL, [[[[pElements objectAtIndex:self.selectedIndexPath.row]objectForKey:@"pdetail"] objectForKey:@"images"] objectForKey:key]];
        NSData* productData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:productURL]];

        if ([UIImage imageWithData:productData]) {
                [self.pageImages addObject:[UIImage imageWithData:productData]];
        }
    }
}

- (void)closeBtnClicked {

    [queue cancelAllOperations];
}
```

**NOTE :** I was using `GCD` (Grand Central Dispatch) for multi-threading, but I came to know that you cannot cancel it, therefore I swicthed to `NSOperationQueue`

Answer (score 0):

Canceling an operation does not magically halt your code dead in its tracks. It is up to *your code* in the operation to check periodically to see whether the operation has been cancelled, and to bow out if so.

Comment: could you please give me a small example ? I thought `cancelAllOperations` will cancel corresponding thread immediately. if not, then what is the purpose of using `[queue cancelAllOperations];` ?

Comment: Did you look at the link I posted? It shows you how to check for cancellation within your operation block.